# ModuleNotFound Import Turtle Dilemma

Tags: python, python-import, importerror

I'm new to python and programming in general, and I wanted to play around with the turtle module, but when I try to import it (I was told it was part of the python library so I did not need to download it) I get an error telling me that there was no module.

The specific error I get in Visual Studio Code is:

File "turtle.py", line 107, in 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'

I have tried `import turtle`, `from turtle import *` and my python file is not named anything related to the turtle module.

Comment: which OS are you using?

Comment: I am using windows 10

Comment: can you check this in command prompt .

Comment: does not work either getting the same error

Comment: and are you using python 2 or 3?

Comment: i am using python 3.6.7